# No se elimina imagen en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, storage

Estoy utilizando File Storage de laravel y quiero eliminar una imagen por medio del controlador
pero no la esta eliminando

este es mi blade

```
@foreach ($imagenes as $key => $value)
   <div><img width="45%" src="{{asset("storage/$value->imagen")}}" />
     <a href="{{ route('delete.imagen',$value->imagen) }}"><span class="material-icons">
                            delete_outline</span></a>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Me muestra mi imagen y le estoy agregando un icono para eliminarlo.

Este es mi route.

```
Route::get('/deleteimage/{imagen}','Artista\ObrasController@destroyimage')->name('delete.imagen');
```

Y este es mi controlador

```
  public function destroyimage($imagen)
{
    Storage::delete($imagen);
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Imagen eliminada exitosamente');
}
```

Y cuando puse directamente el  Storage::delete($imagen); en mi blade si se elimina.

Alguna idea?
GRACIAS

Comment: Qué valor tiene la variable `$imagen` que llega al controlador y dónde está ubicado el archivo que quieres eliminar? Si puedes acceder a la imagen en la etiqueta img con `src="{{asset("storage/$value->imagen")}}"` seguramente el archivo esté en `storage/app/public`, por lo que tendrías que especificarle a `Storage` el directorio, o que use el disco `public`,

Comment: Ya lo logre solucionar, estaba pasando el parametro incorrecto

Comment: Genial, pero por favor resuelve tu pregunta, ya sea con una respuesta o eliminándola si no le va a servir a otros.